# Returning a promise inside a forEach on node v 6.11.5

Tags: javascript, firebase, promise, es6-promise

I'm working on a Firebase Cloud Function which runs on Node v6.11.5 so I can't use Async Await (to my knowledge). The general idea is that I loop through objects, extract data, ping an API on a different server that returns relevant information and then add that new info to an object before adding it to an array and continuing on.

The API returns the info, but not in time. If I log out the object it returns 3 fields, but matches is empty.

Would this be an instance when I should use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) and if so how. I tried creating `getMatches` into a promise, but the function would continue to run.

```
...
const list = [];
...
return db.collection('users').get()
  .then((snapshot) => {
    return snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      const user = doc.data();
      const obj = {};
      obj.id = user.id;
      obj.name = user.name;
      obj.matches = [];

      try {
        getMatches(user.param1, user.param2)
          .then(res => {
            obj.matches.push(res);
          })
      }
      catch (error) {
        console.log('error => ', error);
      }

      list.push(obj);
    });
  })
  .then(() => {
    ... sorts list ...
  })
  .then(() => {
    ... returns list to database ...
  });

const getMatches = function (param1, param2) {
  const url = 'https://something.herokuapp.com/callback.php';
  return axios.post(url, qs.stringify({
      data: param1,
      name: param2
    }))
    .then(res => {
      return res.data;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('ERROR => ', error);
    });
}
```

Comment: You can use async/await if you use TypeScript with your Firebase project.  It will transpile down to ES6, which Cloud Functions will run.  But that still won't help you with dealing with promises in a foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, use Promise.all to check that each getMatches gets resolved (and pushed to the list) before proceeding:

```
return db.collection('users').get()
  .then((snapshot) => {
    const allPromises = snapshot.map((doc) => {
      const user = doc.data();
      const obj = {};
      obj.id = user.id;
      obj.name = user.name;
      obj.matches = [];
      return getMatches(user.param1, user.param2)
        .then(matchPromise => {
          obj.matches.push(res);
          list.push(obj);
        });
    });
    return Promise.all(allPromises);
  })
  .then(() => {
    ... sorts list ...
  })
  .then(() => {
    ... returns list to database ...
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

In `QuerySnapshot` instead of using `forEach` method. There is a properties call `docs` to get result as an array, then you could `map` that into array of Promises.

Ref: [Firebase QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot)

```js
db.collection('users').get()
  .then((querySnapshot) => {
    // 1. Get docs by properties `docs`
    const docs = querySnapshot.docs;
    
    // 2. Use map to convert array of doc into array of promise 
    const getMatchesPromises = docs.map(doc => {
      const user = doc.data();
      return getMatches(user.param1, user.param2)
        .then(res => {
          return {
            id: user.id,
            name: user.name,
            matches: [res],
          }
        });
    });
    
    // 3. Call Promise.all to execute array of promises, 
    // return the result so we can catch them in next then.
    return Promise.all(getMatchesPromises);
  })
  .then(list => {
    // ... your desired result from Promise.all
    /*
    list = [
      { id: 1, name: 'AAA', matches: [...] },
      { id: 2, name: 'BBB', matches: [...] },
    ];
    */
  });
```